# Why doesn't my script include Querystrings and Parameters?

Tags: php, include, require-once

Simply put:

```
<? include("open.php"); ?>
```

VS

```
<? include("open.php?page=about"); ?>
```

VS

```
<? $x="varToPass"; include("open.php"); ?>
```

Why can this not be done, surely this should have been programmed into. And if not can I edit the raw/core PHP C files to achieve this.

Comment: That's because `include` simply includes a file and not a URL. In other words, just echo's out its content

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this question. It may be based on a misapprehension, but since when has that made something a bad question? If the OP knew the truth of the matter, he wouldn't be here asking, would he. +1

Comment: Why do people always get this wrong, `include` (as well as `require`) is a **statement** not a **function**. So you should write it as `include 'file.php'`. See http://at.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: People do not 'always' get this wrong. Beginners may - it is an understandable mistake. You and I have made similar ones in our time, I'm sure.

Comment: @Utkanos - I agree I would like a strong explanation. Also Repped +1

Comment: They get it wrong because 50% out there write it this way and the other that. Doesn't really hurt anyone, does it?

Comment: @Utkanos I agree that this is a valid question, but it is pretty heavy stuff of the OP to write "surely this should have been programmed into". If he is such a beginner to ask that question, then he should think about if he really is that much smarter than all those experienced guys who crafted php. So in a way it IS a mad question.

Comment: Well, alright, yes, the assertion that this would have been 'programmed into' is perhaps a little bold. But again, if you don't know the difference between include/require vs. cURL, you could reasonable mistake the job of one for that of the other.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka it actually **does** make a difference. See Example #4 and #5 in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer. There is no need to pass parameters like this.

`include 'open.php?page=about&something=true&more=rubbish';`

versus

```
$page = 'about';
$something = true;
$more = 'rubbish';

include 'open.php';
```

I think it's quite easy to see which is more readable, and they both achieve exactly what you are trying to do.

The fact is that the `include` statement literally **includes the code from the indicated file** at the point you reference it.

You can treat the file doing the including, as having the source of `open.php` at the exact place you wrote the include statement.

**Edit:**

To answer the second part of your question. Yes you could modify the source and achieve this, but it would be a largely pointless exercise.

**Edit 2:**

It has also occurred to me that perhaps you think you want to include files by URL.

For example `include 'http://127.0.0.1/open.php?page=about'`

In this case it is completely possible, as the `http` stream wrapper will be invoked, and variables will be passed to the file you requested.

This behaviour is **DISABLED BY DEFAULT BECAUSE IT POSES A MASSIVE SECURITY RISK**.

You can turn it on by editing the `allow_url_include` value in `php.ini`. But I suggest that you don't.

Comment: +1 also for the `allow_url_include` accepting query and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

When you include files they will be in the same scope, so you can **re-use variables** or **retrieve parameters**:

```
<?php
    // index file
    $x = $_GET["x"];
    include 'file.php';
```

And in **file.php** you could either do:

```
<?php
    //include file
    if ($x != '')
```

or:

```
<?php
    //include file
    $x = $_GET["x"];
```

So no need to pass things around-

Answer (score -1):

Including/requiring is for physical files, not dynamic representations of files based on incoming parameters.

For the latter, you will need to look into [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: This does not help the OP tbh.

Comment: Was my answer correct and accurate? Yes. Then there is no basis to vote it down, but you may. The question does not require a long answer. Did you want an essay?

Comment: What has `curl` to do with the question?!

Comment: Because cURL *does* allow you to retrieve files (or, rather, their dynamic representations) by passing query strings, so it is entirely possible this is what he was thinking of. I mentioned it in passing at the end of the answer.

Comment: So does php. `include 'http://example.com/foo.php?id=123'` (although the security concerns) works just fine. See example #3 in the docs http://at.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php